# Ubuntu jumps folders when saving files

Tags: nautilus, directory

Whenever I want to save a file in a directory that has 1 sub folder, Ubuntu has this REALLY annoying habit of jumping into that folder when I click save and I specifically ask it to save in the first directory above the sub folder that's there.

I notice this little issue when saving Screenshots too, I tested this out when saving a screenshot to the Desktop while just having 1 new empty folder there, I click to save on just the Desktop from the Screenshot Save Dialogue Box, but it jumps into that folder to save it.

I want to know how I can stop Ubuntu from doing this because it's quite annoying sometimes when I just want it to save to the directory I tell it, and not the other directory folder it THINKS it should be saving to.